# How can I use a base64 encoded sqlite database in Node.js in memory without storing it to disk?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am trying to use a base64 encoded SQLite database with the sqlite3.Database() module.  The first argument should be a string.  I have tested it with a sqlite db saved to disk.  But, for this purpose, I don't want to ever save it to disk.  In this case, I'm decoding a base64 object into an Object, then to a String.

The [documentation for the sqlite3 module](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/connect/) allows you to create an in memory database, but I guess it's created empty and would require additional ddl to start adding tables.

But, if I pass in the String object (as opposed to a quoted string), the sqlite3 module gives the following error:

```
SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
```

The relevant part of the code looks like this:

```
var dbObject = Buffer.from(dbBase64, 'base64');
var dbObj = JSON.stringify(dbObject);
// the next line is where the error occurs
let db = new sqlite3.Database(dbObj, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err.message);
    }
    db.serialize(() => {
        db.each(`SELECT count(*) from TABLE`, (err, row) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
         }
         console.log(row);
       });
    });
 });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question! My first thought is that it's not possible (at least without hacking SQLite to do this). But there might be an alternative... you could create a [RAM disk](https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/create-ramdisk-linux), save the database file to that filesystem, then open it normally. You *might* be able to do it via shell commands from your script, but you'll probably run into permissions issues.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I'm new to node.js and I'm concerned that I might not actually be getting the encoded part of the string passed in.  So, that might be the first problem I need to solve.  For example, looking at my "dbObj" string in the debugger, it looks like a JSON object with {"type" : "Buffer", "data": [ .......]}.  So, I probably need to get the data value out.

Comment: `dbObj` is a Buffer - in this case most likely binary data, held in memory. JSON-encoding it is not going to give you what you want. The buffer is suitable for writing out to a file, or performing other operations. My suggestion was to write it out to a file in RAM: `fs.writeFileSync('filename', dbObj)`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  As I mentioned, I'm new to node and this is taking me down a bit of a rabbit hole.  I'm using VS code. It's complaining about writeFileSync(). `    fstat.writeFileSync('dbObj', dbObject);
          ^

TypeError: fstat.writeFileSync is not a function`

Comment: @Kryten: I just wanted to thank you for your solution.  My problem with implementing your code was that VS Code automatically created the require for me, but it created it as  `const { fstat } = require('fs');`.  I changed it to `const fs = require('fs');` and that allowed writeFileSync to work and I was able to query it.  I hate to be such a noob here.  But, this is my first question to post and I'm not sure how to mark your reply as the solution.  And, I'll post my final code once I figure out how to accept your answer.

Comment: Easy to do in C. Should be easy in Node too if its sqlite bindings provide the [sqlite3_deserialize()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/deserialize.html) function.

Comment: My comment wasn't really intended as a full solution -- more of just a direction you might try, so no need to accept it. I took a look at the `node-sqlite3` package and it does not appear to implement a "deserialize" function like what @Shawn suggested. That's unfortunate, because that looks like exactly what you need.

Comment: @Kryten: Thanks for your effort.  I looked, too.  And, I kept fiddling with other ideas.  But, all I have been able to come up with is your suggestion, which gets me where I want to be, if not all the way, at least mostly.